# ImportError: cannot import name SortedDict - only on Python 2.7, not 2.6

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-2.6

I am trying to get a Django application up and running. The libraries are a bit out of date (its currently on Django 1.4).

I have got it more or less working when I tried python 2.6, but when I change to a virtualenv using python 2.7 I get the error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f057b17c320>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/colin/software/virtualenvs/barshool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/colin/software/virtualenvs/barshool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/home/colin/software/virtualenvs/barshool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "/home/colin/software/virtualenvs/barshool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/colin/software/virtualenvs/barshool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/colin/software/virtualenvs/barshool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/colin/software/virtualenvs/barshool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/colin/software/virtualenvs/barshool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transmeta/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict
ImportError: cannot import name SortedDict
```

I set up the virtualenvs with the same requirements files.

What is the difference between the versions that could be causing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SortedDict` was [removed in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.9/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9). Make sure you have installed the same version of Django in the new virtual environment as the old one.

If it was your own code that was using `SortedDict`, the long term fix would be to update the code to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which was added in Python 2.7. In your case, it looks like the import error is coming from a third party app, which you'll have to update or replace to make the code work with Django 1.9.

Comment: Thanks, now that I check, I did manage to install version 1.9 by accident in that virtualenv. I thought I had 1.4.5 as per the requirements file.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a persistent bug. Meant the same issue while working with `django==1.11.1` and `djangorestframework==3.9.1`. It was particularly djangorestframework (drf) which was importing the `sortedDict`, so i instead updated drf. The latest version at this time is `djangorestframework==3.10.3` [from the python foundation](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework/). This drf upgrade solved my challenge.

Note: I was working with `python 3.6.8`, on `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` (just in case you need those specifics)